# Laravel eloquent model binding for user, who can be a client, admin or producer

Tags: laravel-5

What would be a clean way to retrieve the role model

- id: 1
- name: sample name
- email: email@email.com
- password: pass
- role_type: client
- role_id: 3 ( points to the clients table)

---

- id: 2
- name: sample name2
- email: email2@email.com
- password: pass
- role_type: producer
- role_id: 3 ( points to the producer table)

Goal:

- $user->role -> Client in first case
- $user->role -> Producer in second case

Other solutions to achieve similar functionality are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to user Polymorphic relationships.

If lets say user can be a client and a suppler, user's model needs to have userable relationship and database 2 fiels userable_type (string) and userable_id (int).

Clients and suppliers models relate with:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\User', 'userable');
    }
```